# Stuck on a nested for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, nested

I'm trying to do a nested for loop, that for example will compare adjacent elements. Say I have a list of [2,3,4,5,6], I want to compare 2 to 3, 2 to 4, all the way to 6. After that, I want to go to 3 but I don't want to go back and compare 3 to 2, and I don't want to compare it to itself. Is there anyway to do that? I keep getting a NoneType error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the code you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lookup table to store the previously processed items.

You can try something like this:

```
lst = [2,3,4,5,6]

lut = {item: {} for item in lst} # lookup table

for item1 in lst:
    for item2 in lst:
        if item1 == item2: continue # skip comparing to self

        min_val, max_val = sorted([item1, item2])
        if lut[min_val].get(max_val): continue # skip if already processed

        print(item1, item2) # do the processing here

        lut[min_val][max_val] = True # mark the items processed
```

**output:**

```
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
lst = [2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):
        # compare lst[i] and lst[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

This a classic Dynamic Programming problem. You need to cache your results of adjacent elements in an `n*n` matrix, and use previously populated values at each iteration.

Specifically `matrix[i][j]` is the result of the comparison of elem `i` with elem `j`, which gets populated in the `i`th iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you require:

```py
list_ = [2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(list_)):
  x = list[i]
  for j in range(i+1, len(list_)):
     y = list[j]
     print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase you just want to compare the list.

```
lis=[2,8,4,3,8,9]
length=len(lis)
for i in range(0,length):
    for j in range((i+1),(length-1)):
        if lis[i]<lis[j]:
            print(lis[i],"is smaller",lis[j])
```